# Retaining creation date with unison

Tags: macos, unix, timestamp, unison

Is there a way to retain creation dates using unison? I can preserve the modification times, but I also need creation dates.

**Edit:**
OS in use are BusyBox (EXT4) and OS X (Extended Journal)

Comment: Are you sure your filesystem keeps creation dates? [Most do not](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/22222). What OS are you using and what file system?

Comment: @terdon BusyBox (NAS) and OS X

Comment: So the files are on the NAS? What file system? Also please add [edit] your question to add information, it is easy to miss in the comments and comments can be deleted without warning. Basically, what you're asking for is very dependent on the details of your OS and file system so adding more info to your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @terdon I have updated the post as instructed. the file systems used are EXT4 and Extended Journal